# how to set column data in one table from another table Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have this usecase where I have a table 'a', which has the same columns as table 'b'. What I want is: for all rows that are both in 'a' and 'b', I want 'a' to have the same value for column 'x' as 'b'.

Here is what I'm trying but I keep getting stuck:

```
UPDATE a 
   SET a.x = b.x 
   FROM b  INNER JOIN  a  ON a.id = b.id;
```

Im getting errors:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: table name "a" specified more than once;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there just use below query

```
   UPDATE a 
   SET x = b.x 
   FROM b 
   where 
   a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: When i try this, i get [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column "a" of relation "a" does not exist;

Comment: @SnG the thing the answer should supposed to work but strange why not, can you send me your table structure

Comment: @SnG your error said a does not exist is really a  exist in your db as a table

Comment: appreciate the help - x is a numeric(18,4) that is the same in both tables and schema name as public. I found that out by running the `SELECT *
FROM pg_table_def
WHERE tablename = 'a'
AND schemaname = 'public';`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177630/discussion-between-sng-and-zaynul-abadin-tuhin).

Comment: @SnG I edited according to your solution that you got lastly

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE a
   SET x = b.x
   FROM b
   where a.id = b.id;
```

This ended up working for me